# Проблема с выводом шестнадцатеричных чисел

Tags: c++, вывод, hex

Мне нужно вывести шестнадцатеричный код char'овских символов, но некоторые выводит криво.

Есть массив:

```
char a[91] = { 0x41, 0x0d, 0x61, 0x01, 0x60, 0x44, 0x69, 0x48, 0x24, 0x28, 0x60, 0x24, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x41, 0x04, 0x4c, 0x49, 0x05, 0x24, 0x00, 0x28, 0x60, 0x04, 0x41, 0x0d, 0x61, 0x48, 0x4c, 0x04, 0x41, 0x45, 0x20, 0x6c, 0x40, 0x20, 0x20, 0x29, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x41, 0x60, 0x64, 0x04, 0x41, 0x08, 0x20, 0x2c, 0x49, 0x05, 0x2c, 0x49, 0x48, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x0d, 0x20, 0x64, 0x49, 0x68, 0x25, 0x84, 0x6d, 0x78, 0x9d, 0x98, 0x68, 0x60, 0x60, 0x28, 0x60, 0x60, 0x68, 0x60, 0x04, 0x20, 0x29, 0x60, 0x24, 0x2d, 0x60, 0x24, 0x2d, 0x01, 0x24, 0xc7, 0xb4, 0xd9, 0x38, 0x6c };
```

и его же вывожу:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 91; i++)
{
    cout << hex << (int)a[i] << " ";
}
```

Выводит большинство нормально

```
  6c 40 20 20 29 6c 69 41 60 64 4 41 8 20 2c 49 5 2c 49 48 49 49 49 d 20 64 49 68 25 ffffff84 6d 78 ffffff9d ffffff98 68 60 60 28 60 60 68 60 4 20 29 60 24 2d 60 24 2d 1 24 ffffffc7
```

Но в некоторых почему-то в начало добавляется **fffff**, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Поменяйте массив на 'unsigned char'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип `char` в зависимости от опций компилятора может вести себя либо как `signed char` либо как `unsigned char`.

В вашем случае тип `char` ведет себя как тип `signed char`. В результате символы, которые имеют значение типа `0x84` или `0x9d`, то есть те символы, которые имеют значения, превышающие максимальное положительное значение, которое может храниться в объекте типа `signed char`, которое равно значению.`127`, внутренне представлены отрицательными числами. Отсюда при приведению к типу `int` их знаковый разряд тиражируется в старшие биты числа, представленного в виде объекта типа `int`.

Вам следует объявить массив, как имеющий тип `unsigned char`, либо при выводе на консоль приводить символы массива явно к типу `unsigned char`.

Имейте в виду, что если вы инициализируете массив, используя список в фигурных скобках, то компилятор выдаст диагностическое сообщение, что происходит сужение значения, так как, например, число `0x84`  это положительное число, которое не может быть представлено в типе `signed char`.

В итоге у вас есть два подхода.

Первое. Объявить массив, как имеющий тип `unsigned char` И тогда никаких проблем не будет.

Второе. Имея символьный массив типа `char`, выводить его элементы, используя явное приведение символов массива к типу `unsigned char`.

Ниже приведена программа, которая демонстрирует оба подхода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 91;

    unsigned char a[N] = 
    { 
        0x41, 0x0d, 0x61, 0x01, 0x60, 0x44, 0x69,  
        0x48, 0x24, 0x28, 0x60, 0x24, 0x2d, 0x2d, 
        0x41, 0x04, 0x4c, 0x49, 0x05, 0x24, 0x00, 
        0x28, 0x60, 0x04, 0x41, 0x0d, 0x61, 0x48, 
        0x4c, 0x04, 0x41, 0x45, 0x20, 0x6c, 0x40, 
        0x20, 0x20, 0x29, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x41, 0x60, 
        0x64, 0x04, 0x41, 0x08, 0x20, 0x2c, 0x49, 
        0x05, 0x2c, 0x49, 0x48, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 
        0x0d, 0x20, 0x64, 0x49, 0x68, 0x25, 0x84, 
        0x6d, 0x78, 0x9d, 0x98, 0x68, 0x60, 0x60, 
        0x28, 0x60, 0x60, 0x68, 0x60, 0x04, 0x20, 
        0x29, 0x60, 0x24, 0x2d, 0x60, 0x24, 0x2d, 
        0x01, 0x24, 0xc7, 0xb4, 0xd9, 0x38, 0x6c 
    };

    char b[N];

    std::memcpy( b, a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw( 2 ) << static_cast<int>( a[i] );

        std::cout << ( ( i + 1 ) % 7 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ' );                 

    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw( 2 )
                  << static_cast<int>( static_cast<unsigned char>( b[i] ) );

        std::cout << ( ( i + 1 ) % 7 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ' );                 

    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль выглядит следующим образом

```
41  d 61  1 60 44 69
48 24 28 60 24 2d 2d
41  4 4c 49  5 24  0
28 60  4 41  d 61 48
4c  4 41 45 20 6c 40
20 20 29 6c 69 41 60
64  4 41  8 20 2c 49
 5 2c 49 48 49 49 49
 d 20 64 49 68 25 84
6d 78 9d 98 68 60 60
28 60 60 68 60  4 20
29 60 24 2d 60 24 2d
 1 24 c7 b4 d9 38 6c

41  d 61  1 60 44 69
48 24 28 60 24 2d 2d
41  4 4c 49  5 24  0
28 60  4 41  d 61 48
4c  4 41 45 20 6c 40
20 20 29 6c 69 41 60
64  4 41  8 20 2c 49
 5 2c 49 48 49 49 49
 d 20 64 49 68 25 84
6d 78 9d 98 68 60 60
28 60 60 68 60  4 20
29 60 24 2d 60 24 2d
 1 24 c7 b4 d9 38 6c
```

Answer (score 3):

Приводите не к `int`, а к `unsigned char` - это самое корректное решение, поскольку при приведении к `int` вступает в игру знаковость, которая вам совсем не нужна. Размеры `unsigned char` и `char` совпадают, так что неприятностей не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Убирайте лишние биты, которые образуются из-за знака (значение `char` больше `CHAR_MAX` воспринимается как отрицательное со всеми вытекающими последствиями):

```
cout << hex << (int)(a[i] & UCHAR_MAX) << " ";
```

Comment: Знаковость char зависит от реализации. А значит и диапазон хранимых чисел.

Comment: OK, `UCHAR_MAX` сойдёт?

Comment: @ wchar_t стандартно

Comment: @PinkTux Подумалось - а чисто теоретически, если на машине хитрое представление, не основанное на дополнении до двух? Типа прямого кода?...

Comment: @PinkTux мой комментарий был про 127, а не про битовую маску. По маске тоже вопрос любопытный, уже Harry озвучил.

Comment: @user31238, не понял. Что стандартно, где, почему?

Comment: Используется для расширенных символов(это они и есть)

Comment: @user31238, кто они, где, какое отношение `wchar_t` имеет к обсуждаемому вопросу? хотелось бы услышать развёрнутую гипотезу, а не невнятные обрывки каких-то мыслей.